# how i can get the searchText from a form with input search here maps javascript

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

```
function geocode(text,platform) {

var geocoder = platform.getGeocodingService(),
geocodingParameters = {
  searchText: 'Sidi allal tazi 14052 kenitra',
  jsonattributes : 1
};
```

Calling function

```
geocoder.geocode(geocodingParameters,onSuccess,onError);
```

How can I get those input places mapped by using the above function?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the location on the map like this:

[...]

```
/**
 * Calculates and displays the address details of 200 S Mathilda Ave, Sunnyvale, CA
 * based on a free-form text
 *
 *
 * A full list of available request parameters can be found in the Geocoder API documentation.
 * see: http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-geocode.html
 *
 * @param   {H.service.Platform} platform    A stub class to access HERE services
 */
function geocode(platform) {
  var geocoder = platform.getGeocodingService(),
    geocodingParameters = {
      searchText: '200 S Mathilda Sunnyvale CA',
      jsonattributes : 1
    };

  geocoder.geocode(
    geocodingParameters,
    onSuccess,
    onError
  );
}
/**
 * This function will be called once the Geocoder REST API provides a response
 * @param  {Object} result          A JSONP object representing the  location(s) found.
 *
 * see: http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-type-response-geocode.html
 */
function onSuccess(result) {
  var locations = result.response.view[0].result;
 /*
  * The styling of the geocoding response on the map is entirely under the developer's control.
  * A representitive styling can be found the full JS + HTML code of this example
  * in the functions below:
  */
  addLocationsToMap(locations);
  addLocationsToPanel(locations);
  // ... etc.
}
```

[...]

Comment: i need to find places in map by a search bar